# Intercepting errors and panics in Go

Tags: go, error-handling, panic

I'm creating a CLI just to learn a bit more about Go. Is it possible to intercept all errors and panics, so I can have one unique place to handle them, and also format it and after print to stdout.

Example:

Instead of using:

```
x, err := doSomething()
if err != nil {
  errorHandler.Handler(err)
}
```

I could just use initialize the code that can intercept all errors before doing anything:

```
errorHandler.New()
```

And then I could just "ignore" all errors:

```
x, _ := doSomething()
```

Is that a bad practice with Go?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics But you cannot convert errors to panics. And yes. That _is_ bad practice, very bad indeed.

Comment: Errors are returned for a reason, and not handling them will lead to defects.

Answer (score 2):

Errors are just values in go. Just like there's no way to intercept any time a function returns a string, there's no way to intercept errors.